# C# Telegram Bot. Getupdate method

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

Telegram api uses [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method to return messages and offset for update_id. How can i get last message properly?

Answer (score 4):

You should store last Update_id in your database and in your next request pass it to telegram +1 using offset parameter in your query.